# Why does my submit button fail to trigger Javascript MVC?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple code from a book and the code should display data from my controller in the "results" span.  What am I missing?

Controller...

```
    public string GetQuote(string symbol)
    {
        if (symbol.Trim() != "")
            return "99";
        else
            return "Sorry";
    }
```

ASPX...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Index
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<%using (Html.BeginForm("GetQuote","Stocks", new { id = "quoteForm" })) { %>

    Symbol: 
<%= Html.TextBox("symbol") %>
<input type="submit" />
<span id="results"></span>
<% } %>
<p><i><%=DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() %></i></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form[action~='GetQuote']").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            $("#results").html(response);
        });
        return false;
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You selector only matches `<form>` elements where the `action` parameter *ends with* `GetQuote`.
You need to change it to `form[action~='GetQuote']` to match `<form>` elements where the `action` parameter *contains* `GetQuote`.

Alternatively, you can add an ID to your form, like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("GetQuote","Stocks", new { id = "quoteForm" }))
```

and change the selector to `#quoteForm`.

Comment: I added the id and changed to $("quoteForm[action~='GetQuote']")... and I am still being directed to another page

Comment: You need to move your `<script>` block below the `<form>`.

Comment: It didnt change :( ... See Edits

Comment: Change it to either `#quoteForm` **or** `form[action~='GetQuote']`, and read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) so that you can understand your mistake.

Comment: The change still gave the same result.  I will check out the documentation and hopefully I can see the error

Comment: I am still not able to get thru using the javascript... Ajax.BeginForm() gets the job done, but I will need more freedom than what is allowed on that approach.

Answer (score 0):

While SLaks answer did lead me in the right direction... I was missing the DOM call...

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[action$='GetQuote']").submit(function() { 
    ...
});
```